# WinDDK : Running My First Driver

Tags: c, driver, device-driver, wdk

I'm just getting my feet wet with driver programming, but I can't seem to run. Wen i try to load my driver with the OSRLoader tool, i get an error message: This Driver has been blocked from loading.

My system: Win 7 64 bit, AVG Antivirus free, latest winDDK. Compiled, the driver sys file is 4kb. I build it with the x86 checked build environment.

Code

```
#include <ntddk.h>

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT pDriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING pRegistryPath){
    DbgPrint("Hello World!\n");
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Makefile:

```
!INCLUDE $(NTMAKEENV)\makefile.def
```

sources

```
TARGETNAME=helloworld
TARGETTYPE=DRIVER
TARGETPATH=MyDriver

INCLUDES=..\inc  
SOURCES = Main.c
```

How can I get this to run?

Comment: Does the error message say why the driver was blocked from loading?  Not found in path?  Invalid format?  Lack of permission?

Comment: My guesses: Either you're trying to load 32-bit code on a 64-bit OS, or you don't have Disable Driver Signature Enforcement set since 64-bit drivers normally have to be signed on Vista/7.

Comment: It doesnt give any specific error a, i pretty sure i have the right architecture compiled and ofcourse i run as uac admin, i haved looked into  signature enforment, ill try that,thanks

Comment: ChrisV is correct: you have to disable signature enforcement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to install your driver.

this can be done by using INF file and app that call devcon.exe from the WDK.
you will need to create INF which root\XXX "hardware id".

I would refer to the [toaster sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in WDK, it is very good sample to learn to write drivers.

Answer (score 0):

It shows "This Driver has been blocked from loading" because you built the driver with x86 build env on x64 machine.
Building it with x64 Free/Checked build will work!